# How to access an object within an array in node

Tags: node.js, schema, ejs

I am trying to access body inside blog schema. How can I do it.

***Schema:***

```
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  blog: [{
    topic: { type: String, unique: false, lowercase: true },
    body: {  type: String, unique: false, lowercase: true },
    tags: [ 'first', 'mongodb', 'express'],
    created: Date,
    modified: { type : Date, default : Date.now },
    state: {  type: String, unique: false, lowercase: true }
    }]
});
```

**

**router**

**

```
router.get('/blog/article/:postid', function (req, res, next) {
  Article.findById({ _id: req.params.postid }, function (err, article) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.render('main/publishedArticle', {
      article: article,
      message: req.flash('showing article ' + article.title)
    });
  });
});
```

**

**publishedArticle.ejs**

**

```
<h3><%= article.blog.body %></h3>
```

**I am am getting undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared your blog schema as an array of objects (note that you've used the [ ] around the object for a blog item). If that was intentional, then you need to access various *blog* elements of your article with an array index (or iterate over them using a loop). The snippet below assumes that your article has at least one blog entry saved:

```
<h3><%= article.blog[0].body %></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks so simple